How to access installed packages from an Android app?
Can a non-system installed app access the /data/app folders where installed package files are stored? I know they are accessible using a file explorer app but how would this be implemented in an Android app?
I’m not sure how to test this outside of writing a specific app

"I know they are accessible using a file explorer app" -- not without access to some sort of root facility.

Your application must have ROOT permission on the rooted device.
